# Android Manifest INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE string resource Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have replaced the app version and name variables in my manifest file with resource references. The issue that is occurring now though is that regardless of what number I set in my resources file the app still gives this error.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

This is the change ive made to the manifest

```
android:versionCode="@integer/version_code"
android:versionName="@string/version_name" >
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how I might be able to correct it?

Comment: Gradle is replacing the `versionCode` and `versionName` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` if they're set in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Leandros I dont follow. Ive set the versionCode in integer.xml and version name in string.sml. They are not set in the build.gradle..

Comment: Remove the current installed application on your phone, and install it again. The `versionCode` of the application on your phone seems to be lower than the in your app current app.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gradle for building your APKs. Your `build.gradle` file is replacing the `versionCode` and `versionName` values in the androidManifest file. So doesn't matter where you've defined your code and version name. When you change those values directly in your manifest, they'll always be overridden by gradle.

`consumer {
            versionCode 123
            versionName "1.0.0"
            applicationId "com.example.android"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        }`

Removing your current installation of your apk and reinstalling will also solve this problem.